How to reference dynamic product info in a category text
I want to be able to reference the price of a certain product in a category text, but this price will change over time, so I want to reference it dynamically.
Is this natively achievable?
If no, how would I create plugin for this?

That depend on how price need to fetch Dynamic there?

I don't fully understand your comment, but I want to use the price of a specific product in a category text and I want it to auto update when the price of that product changes
